# pgfplotstable: Columns from defined List

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a table

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
}\mytable
```

with columns 0,1,...,6.

Why can't I say `\def\List{0,3,5}` and then

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={\List}    %    Works not
]{\mytable}
```

What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,
every head row/.style={after row=\hline},
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
}\mytable
\begin{document}
\section{Main Table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable}

\section{Works}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={0,3,5}]{\mytable}

\section{List works not}
\def\List{0,3,5}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
%columns=\List        %   Works not 
%columns={\List}    %    Works not
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `/.expanded` key is for.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,
every head row/.style={after row=\hline},
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
}\mytable
\begin{document}
\section{Main Table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mytable}

\section{Works}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={0,3,5}]{\mytable}

\section{List works not}
\def\List{0,3,5}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/.expanded=\List        %   Works
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TYVM! This helps me a lot!